# Short conditional statement in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm looking for short conditional statement in python/django templates, so I could write less and reuse more. Something like (tkey in disabled_rows) ? "disabled-row" : "".

Here's what I'm doing:

```
{% if tkey in disabled_rows %}
    <tr class="disabled-row">
{% else %}  
    <tr>    
{% endif %}
```

I also tried a custom template tag without success:

```
{{ (tkey in disabled_rows)|xif:'true,false' }}
```

xif implementation:

```
def xif(cond, args):
if cond:
    return args.split(',')[0]
else:
    return args.split(',')[1]
```

Extra points if you can explain why this is not implemented natively in python.

Comment: Your custom filter duplicates the built-in `yesno` filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno

Comment: The above link is no longer working, here's newer one if anyone needs it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the example you gave, this solution is short and simple:

```
<tr {% if tkey in disabled_rows %} class="disabled-row"{% endif %}>
```

Perhaps there is something else you're trying to achieve that would be better elucidated with a different example?